# Angular 6 and bpmn-properties-panel

Tags: angular6, typescript2.0, angular7, bpmn.io

I am trying to use bpmn.io in my project.
So i tried to integrate [bpmn-properties-panel](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-properties-panel) with Angular.

I had installed all the modules and imported them.
But i am not getting all the properties what they are showing.

[image: Example given by bpmn.io]

What i am getting is below image

[image]

As you can see i am not able to see all the properties of specific task.

and i went through their official forum [Angular 6 and properties-panel](https://forum.bpmn.io/t/angular-5-6-and-the-bpmn-js-properties-panel/2670/3)

and if i do like that

```
import camundaModdleDescriptor from 'camunda-bpmn-moddle/resources/camunda.json';
```

i am getting error

```
Cannot find module 'camunda-bpmn-moddle/resources/camunda.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

Help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Camunda.json` file [here](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-moddle/blob/master/resources/camunda.json)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is explained in the error. you need to enable the resolveJsonModule option from tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

more informations in this link: 
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/importing-json-modules-in-typescript